# Is there a way to ensure local fonts load from CDN when CDN is enabled?

Tags: optimization, cdn, fonts

I've set up a WordPress site with one local font. It is stored in the a `fonts` folder in the child theme. It is loaded with the following in the child theme `style.css`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Last Paradise';
    src: url('fonts/LastParadise.eot');
    src: url('fonts/LastParadise.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/LastParadise.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/LastParadise.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/LastParadise.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/LastParadise.svg#LastParadise') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The site has a CDN, which is currently activated by the `bunny.net` CDN plug-in. Although I've tried various other options, such as the `CDN Enabler` plug-in from KeyCDN, and also via the CDN options that are in various caching plug-ins I've tested.

In all cases, the above-mentioned font does not load from the CDN. It is called from the website URI.

I notice that there are a couple of other fonts that are loaded by plug-ins, and these also loading from the site URI not the CDN URI.

#### Questions

1. Is there a specific way to import/enqueue/reference a local font such that its URI will be picked up by a CDN plug-in, and thus converted to using the CDN URI when CDN is enabled? (I realise I could put in the full CDN based URI in the above `@font-face` CSS, but I'd like to know if there's a way to reference the font locally, such that when CDN is enabled then its URI will be converted to CDN URI.
2. Is there a way to over-ride (like to de-enqueue and then re-enqueue) fonts that are being loaded by plug-ins? Such that I could force it to load from the CDN URI (by using the full CDN based URI when re-referencing it?)

Comment: It depends entirely on the plugin. You will need to ask its author.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - as in the plug-in that is enabling the CDN ?

Comment: Yes. There isn't a generic answer. It depends on what CDN and plugin you're using, and whether that plugin supports adding theme assets to the CDN.

Comment: All the theme assets are successfully being called from the CDN without issue, such as CSS, JS, png and svg files. It's just this one font that seems to be an exception.

Comment: Again, you need to speak to the plugin author.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - Thanks for your input. I think you're being overly dismissive, which I find unhelpful. Especially if you're the person who voted to close the topic. The issue you're referring to in these comments is only one aspect of my question.

Comment: I'd say Jacob's just being succinct :) . I think he's right with regards to all aspects of your question... #1 - there is no font-reference format standard that any majority of CDN plugins have agreed to use and offload when encountered. #2 fonts are not first-class citizens of the WordPress asset loading system, so they do not get unique handles or references in the WordPress software, and most extensions load fonts via scripts or styles rather than a dedicated loading mechanism. So the answer in all cases is to inspect the relevant code, or to contact the relevant authors.

Comment: @bosco - Thanks for sharing your thoughts. All good points. Yet, as you'll see in the "answer" I've shared below, this problem had nothing to do with the 6 or so plug-ins I tested for CDN redirection. So, in my opinion, it was jumping to false conclusions to assume numerous CDN plug-ins were all at fault. Surely we would see a lot of online discussion (and forum questions, etc., such as what I posted here on SE) by people struggling to get font files to load from a CDN, if the most popular CDN plug-ins for WordPress were all affected by an issue such as this.

Comment: I see... This is a bit of a complicated situation, I think. I wrote my thoughts to address the specific questions you posed. Any conclusions I made were based on the information provided therein. There was no indication of a potential plugin conflict. Nor was I trying to cast blame on the CDN plugins - I was merely stating how they handle fonts depends entirely on the plugin. The Answer as posted does not address either of the questions. It does detail overriding `@font-face` declarations - but that is only one of many possibilities. In any scenario, I'm glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I will post my findings here as they will likely be useful to anyone else facing a similar situation.

I had considered whether the issue was with the CDN redirection implemented on the site (a plug-in). But the fact that every (3 of the most popular) CDN plug-ins I tried, and every cache plug-in with CDN settings (3 widely used cache plug-ins), had the same result suggested to me that was not the source of the issue.

After looking more extensively into this situation, what I have found is that this issue was caused by the `Aggregate CSS-files` feature of the popular [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) plug-in.

I found that Autoptimize provides a way around this. It is explained in the [FAQ here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/#faq).

To me, this discovery makes an important point, which is worth noting. *Anyone else finding that their CDN implementation is mostly working, but some font (or perhaps some other assets) are not loading via their chosen CDN redirection method (such as any of the popular CDN enabling plug-ins) should first consider that **the issue is likely caused by a conflict with another plug-in***.
If you are using the somewhat popular Autoptimise plug-in, or any other optimisation plug-in that aggregates CSS files, that should  be one of the first things troubleshoot.

In direct answer to the two questions:

1. All popular CDN redirection plug-ins should have no issue redirecting the URI for fonts loaded via `@font-face { ... }` in the CSS from the theme assets and from plug-in assets. If they appear to be having such an issue, it is most likely another plug-in that's at fault (as noted above).
2. In WordPress there is no `dequeue` then (re)`enqueue` equivalent for `@font-face` declarations. You would have to dequeue the entire CSS file in question, and enqueue a modified version of it (with the hard-coded CDN URIs). Not useful, and not advisable.

### Over-riding @font-face declarations

Should the need arise (not the case in this instance, now that it's clear another plug-in was the cause of the issue) to over-ride an `@font-face { ... }` declaration in the CSS files of any plug-in, etc., you can do so by declaring that same `@font-face { ... }` yourself. You can then hard-code in the font file sources to what you need them to be. I tested this by declaring a number of `@font-face { ... }` statements via the popular [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plug-in. Doing this effectively changed the source locations of the font faces in question. One scenario this could come in handy is if you want to locally source a font that a plug-in is pulling in from a remote source.